# newman occur 403 Forbidden

Tags: postman, cloudflare, http-status-code-403, newman

Newman Version (can be found via newman -v): 5.3.0

OS details (type, version, and architecture): win10 x64

Are you using Newman as a library, or via the CLI? CLI

Did you encounter this recently, or has this bug always been there:
i export a collection as episode2.json from postman, the request doing well in postman, then i try to use the episode2.json in newman to write the response to disk, but it's failed with 403 Forbidden
Expected behaviour: do not trigger 403 Forbidden

here is js for newman

```
const newman = require('newman'),
fs = require('fs');

newman.run({
    collection: require('./episode2.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('request', function (error, args) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        fs.writeFile(`002.ts`, args.response.stream, function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });        
    }
});
```

her is my import json for postman

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "",
        "name": "episode2",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "002",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                    "connection": true,
                    "user-agent": true
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "authority",
                        "value": "t.wdubo.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "method",
                        "value": "GET",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "scheme",
                        "value": "https",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "accept-language",
                        "value": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "origin",
                        "value": "https://m.duboku.fun",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "referer",
                        "value": "https://m.duboku.fun/",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "user-agent",
                        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://v.zdubo.com/20211215/lyEJ5Nhc/hls/tyKYGEaE.ts",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "v",
                        "zdubo",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "20211215",
                        "lyEJ5Nhc",
                        "hls",
                        "tyKYGEaE.ts"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

please help me!
Regards

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQMjg.png)

[newman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tu1f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Issue didn't reproduce on my setup. It is running fine and downloaded a 2.33 MB video file which got saved properly. So not a newman issue

Maybe there is some privilege issue for the drive where you are trying to save the video clip.

[image: File downloaded]

[image: CLI Output]